# Showing Barplots aside Table - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to show barplots and the data frame they were generated from side by side for reporting purposes. For example I have the following dataframe:

```
> green
   Player.Name  Tm at Opp W/L    MP FG FGA x3P x3PA FT FTA ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF PTS USG. Line   MB    DS     Date
Draymond Green GSW    SAS   L 32:37  7  14   2    5  2   2   5   7  12   6   5   1   2  2  18 22.8   29 51.4 55.25 20161025
Draymond Green GSW  @ NOP   W 34:04  3  10   1    2  1   2   4   7  11   7   2   0   3  5   8 16.7   -8 32.7 33.75 20161028
Draymond Green GSW  @ PHO   W 37:47  2   9   0    4  1   2   1  12  13   9   0   3   2  3   5 13.4   -6 38.1 37.75 20161030
Draymond Green GSW  @ POR   W 30:01  2   3   1    2  1   2   0   8   8   9   3   2   0  2   6  5.4  -23 39.1 40.00 20161101
Draymond Green GSW    OKC   W 29:10  2   9   0    2  5   6   4   6  10   5   1   4   4  3   9 22.6  -26 34.5 35.00 20161103
Draymond Green GSW  @ LAL   L 33:41  6  10   0    3  4   6   2   7   9   4   4   0   1  1  16 16.9   20 39.8 39.25 20161104
Draymond Green GSW    NOP   W 34:42  2   7   0    1  0   0   2  10  12  11   2   2   2  3   4 11.3  -10 40.9 43.25 20161107
Draymond Green GSW    DAL   W 34:36  6  11   4    6  0   1   1   9  10   4   0   2   1  3  16 17.5  -21 37.0 42.50 20161109
Draymond Green GSW  @ DEN   W 28:46  4   7   3    4  2   2   0   9   9   5   3   0   1  2  13 13.6  -24 36.3 39.50 20161110
Draymond Green GSW    PHO   W 37:01  4  10   1    5  5   5   2   5   7  11   3   2   3  3  14 16.9  -13 45.9 49.25 20161113
Draymond Green GSW  @ TOR   W 34:54  5  13   1    4  0   0   0   7   7   5   2   3   3  4  11 19.8   -6 33.9 34.75 20161116
Draymond Green GSW  @ BOS   W 35:09  3  11   2    6  3   4   1   7   8   8   1   1   1  3  11 17.7  -16 35.6 36.25 20161118
Draymond Green GSW  @ MIL   W 35:31  3   7   0    1  4   4   1   1   2   5   3   2   2  3  10 12.0   -3 27.9 28.00 20161119
Draymond Green GSW  @ IND   W 29:25  4   7   0    2  2   2   3   6   9   7   2   2   1  1  10 12.5  -37 38.3 38.50 20161121
```

And from this I create barplots using:

```
barplot(green$MB,names.arg=green$Date,las=2,main="Draymond Green MB Fantasy Points")
```

[image: Draymond Green MB Fantasy Points]

```
barplot(green$DS,names.arg=green$Date,las=2,main="Draymond Green DS Fantasy Points")
```

[image: Draymond Green DS Fantasy Points]

What I want to be able to do is create an output like the following. Barplots aligned vertically and the dataframe aligned to the right (preferably centred vertically but not essential).

[image: Combined Barplots and Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ggplot2:

```
green$Date <- as.factor(green$Date)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
grid.arrange(
  ggplot(green, aes(Date, MB)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5)) + ggtitle('Draymond Green MB Fantasy Points'),
  ggplot(green, aes(Date, DS)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5)) + ggtitle('Draymond Green DS Fantasy Points'),
  tableGrob(green), ncol=4, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,3,3,3),c(2,3,3,3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layout()` function along with `gplots` package. Exemple:

```
library(gplots)

layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3), nrow = 2))
hist(rnorm(100))
hist(rnorm(50))
textplot(head(iris))
```

[image]